# Finding remainder on division by 2014

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm trying to find the remainder when $6^{936}$ is divided by $2014$

I started thinking I could use Euler's theorem but then noticed that $6$ isn't prime, I then tried to split it into $6=2 \times 3$ but have got stuck now and don't know how to continue?

Comment: Six not being a prime is not necessarily a problem. But the fact that it has a common factor with $2014$ is. Have you covered Chinese remainder theorem yet?

Comment: I have but I'm not very confident with it at all. I tend to use a long winded approach and avoid CRT at all costs >.<

Comment: Have you tried to figure out the remainder of $6^{936}$ when divided by $2014/2=1007$ and when divided by $2$? Put those two results together, and you have it. Hmm. On second thought I'm not sure this is any easier.

Comment: Except that if you observe that $1007=53\cdot19$, it becomes a lot easier :-) $936=(53-1)(19-1)$.

Answer (score 4):

As $2014=2\cdot19\cdot53,$

$$6^{936}\equiv0\pmod2\  \ \ \ (1)$$

$$936\equiv0\pmod{18}\implies6^{936}\equiv1\pmod{19}$$

$$936\equiv0\pmod{52}\implies6^{936}\equiv1\pmod{53}$$

$$\implies6^{936}\equiv1\pmod{19\cdot53}\  \ \ \ (2)$$

**Method** $\#1:$ Chinese remainder theorem on $(1),(2)$

**Method** $\#2: 6^{936}=1+1007a$ where $a$ is any integer

As $6$ is even, $a$ must be odd $=2b+1$(say) where $b$ is any integer

$$\implies6^{936}=1+1007(2b+1)\equiv1+1007\pmod{2\cdot1007}$$

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to continue: By the Euler-Fermat theorem, you know how to work out the remainders of $2^{936}$ and $3^{936}$ modulo $2014.$ Suppose the remainders are $a$ and $b$ so that

$$ 2^{936} = 2014 \alpha + a \ , \ 3^{936} = 2014 \beta + b$$ for some integers $\alpha, \beta. $ Now if you multiply these, you see that $$ 6^{936} = 2014^2 \alpha \beta + 2014 \alpha b + 2014 a\beta + ab.$$

Modulo 2014, this is $ab.$ In a similar way, you should prove that if $n = a \pmod k$ and $m=b \pmod k$ then $nm = ab \pmod k.$

An alternative method is the Chinese Remainder Theorem, which you should not avoid. Ask your lecturer to help you through some examples. What CRT does is reduce the problem to finding $6^{936}$ modulo the prime factors of 2014 (= 2 * 19 * 53). The product of the remainders mod 2, 19 and 53 is then the remainder mod 2014. With this approach, you can get by with just Fermat's Little Theorem (which Euler generalized) since now you just need to compute remainders after dividing by prime numbers.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\ $ Specialize $\,a,p,q = 6,19,53\,$ and $\ e = (p\!-\!1)(q\!-\!1) = 936\,$ in the following

**Lemma** $\ $ If $\ a,p,q\, $ are pairwise coprime, $\,p,q$ odd, and $\ \phi(p),\phi(q)\mid e\,$ then $$\,a^e\equiv\, 1+a'pq\!\pmod{2pq}\ \ \ {\rm for}\ \ \ a' = (a\!-\!1\ {\rm mod}\ 2)$$

**Proof** $\,\ {\rm mod}\ p\!:\ a^e \equiv (a^{\large \phi(p)})^{\large e/\phi(p)}\!\!\overset{\rm {Euler}}{\underset{\large (a,p)=1}\equiv} 1.\,$ Similarly $\,a^e\equiv 1\pmod q\ $ by $\ (a,q)= 1.$

So $\ p,q\mid a^e-1\,\Rightarrow\,pq\mid a^e-1\,\Rightarrow\,a^e = 1 + jpq,\,\ j\in\Bbb Z\ $ by $\,{\rm lcm}(p,q) = pq\,$ by $\,p,q\,$ coprime.

${\rm mod}\ 2\!:\ a \equiv a^e = 1 + jpq \overset{p,q\ \rm odd}\equiv 1\!+\!j\!\iff\! j\equiv a\!-\!1\equiv a',\ $ i.e. $\ j = a'\!+\!2k,\ k\in\Bbb Z$

Therefore $\ a^e = 1+jpq = 1\!+\!(a'\!+\!2k)pq \equiv 1+a'pq\pmod{2pq}\ \ $ **QED**